# Schema Name Sql server from java jdbc connection

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

i am trying to call **stored procedures** from java using **jdbc** conenction 
to connect sql server

```
String storedProcd = "{call TEST_PROC(?,?)}";
callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(storedProcd);
callableStatement.setInt(1, id);
callableStatement.setString(2, Entityname);
callableStatement.execute();
callableStatement.close();
```

problem is that i cant set schema name in **JDBC** url,it works fine if my Stored procuders are in default schema that is **dbo** but what if my stored procedures are in other schema ?

Comment: hi thanks Leos ,working fine .Please post it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As any SQL resource you can prefix procedure name with schema name:

```
"{call schema.TEST_PROC(?,?)}"
```